# List specific value first

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2005

I searched this everywhere but cannot find any solution, I need to list a specific city like 'New York' first in the following sql statement, I tried to place 
          ORDER BY CASE City.name_en
          WHEN 'New York' THEN 1
          ELSE 2 END ,City.name_en 
in the inner sql statement but did not work, is there any workaround to solve this?

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT RTRIM(Organization.name_en) as '@name','flag.png'  AS  '@flag',
    RTRIM(Country.name_en) as 'country',RTRIM(city.name_en) as 'city',Organization.id as 'OrganizationID',
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY sequence_num) AS RowNum
FROM Organization 
LEFT JOIN City ON City.id = city_id
LEFT JOIN Country ON country.id = Organization.country_id
LEFT JOIN Industry ON Industry.id = Industry_id
WHERE 
 (industry_id =@industry_id OR Coalesce(@industry_id,'') = '')
AND (Organization.name_en LIKE '%' + @OrganizationName + '%' OR Coalesce(@OrganizationName,'') = '')
) AS SOD

WHERE    SOD.RowNum BETWEEN ((@PageNumber-1)*@RowsPerPage)+1
AND @RowsPerPage*(@PageNumber)

FOR XML PATH('organization'), ROOT('organizations')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I solved it like this:

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CASE city.name_en
           WHEN @cityName THEN 1 
           ELSE 2 END ,city.name_en) AS RowNum
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `ORDER BY FIELD`
For example:-

```
ORDER BY FIELD(City.name_en, 'New York', 'CA')
```

It will give you expected result.

Comment: This is a SQL Server question not MySql!

Comment: Check this out - http://www.youdidwhatwithtsql.com/ordering-by-column-value-in-sql-server-mysql/384/

Comment: I already tried this but did not get the expected result, I already mentioned this in my question

Answer (score 0):

use Union

example

Select country_code, country_name from country where country_name ='New York'

union all

Select country_code, country_name from country where country_name != 'New York' 
order by country_name

Comment: In the query you can see that first is specific type .i.e 'New York' and union all without Union. Insert it into a temporary table and even you can have prmary key with auto generated number. You "select * from tempTable order by ID asc". It will be in the sequence you want. I hope it will help